# while cicle in nltk in py3

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, nltk

I have this task:
"Find the distribution of hapax as the corpus increases for
incremental portions of 1000 tokens (1000 tokens, 2000 tokens, 3000 tokens, etc.)"
i tought to use a while cicle in this way:

```
 def funzIncrem (testo) :
  while i in testo < len(testo) :
     testo = testo [0 : i]
     fDist = FreqDist (testo)
     hapax = len(fDist.hapaxes())
     distHapax = hapax/i
     i += 1000
     print (distHapax)
  return
```

but when i run it the interpreter give me:
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment"

i tryed in various ways but i can't find the right one. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def funzIncrem(testo):
    i = 1000
    while i in testo < len(testo):
        testo = testo[0: i]
        fDist = FreqDist(testo)
        hapax = len(fDist.hapaxes())
        distHapax = hapax / i
        i += 1000
        print(distHapax)
    return
```

I initialize the variable i with the statement.

```
i=1000
```

When I omit the statement the variable i has no value and the interpreter does not know what to do when it encounters i.

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment"

The variable i is local to the scope of the function funzIncrem. This kind of scope is called Function scope. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Function_scope.

UnboundLocalError is explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=unboundlocalerror#UnboundLocalError.

Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)

Good luck!